# Typescript: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Store' before initialization

Tags: typescript, oop, inheritance

I have a class Store which incapsulates State (mobx used).

```
export class Store<State> {
    @observable
    public state: State;

    constructor(protected rootStore: RootStore, state: State) {
        this.state = state || ({} as State);
    }

    @action
    setState(state: State) {
        this.state = {
            ...this.state,
            ...state
        };
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to implement a class `UserState`:

```
interface UserState {
    authorised?: boolean;
    loading?: boolean;
    name?: string;
    balance?: number;
}

export class UserStore extends Store<UserState> {
    constructor(rootStore: RootStore) {
        super(rootStore, {
            authorised: false,
            loading: true,
            name: ''
        })
    }
}
```

Everything seems right for me, but I have an error:

`ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Store' before initialization`

I simply trying to set some default values in a store and it seems in a `Store` it's inside a constructor, so it's initialized obviously.

[image]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Problem was solved by moving `Store` class to isolated file, before it was in the same file as the global store.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to transpile issues, you could also declare `Store` class before `UserStore` class.